# Ignore Order in Oracle Text Contains Search

Tags: sql, oracle, text

Let's say I have 2 rows in my Oracle Text index like:

```
Row 1 'John Smith Bristol South West'
Row 2 'John James Smith London South East'
```

What is the best and most efficient way to do the following searches:

1. If I provide the search term: **John Smith** or **Smith John**, both rows should be returned but Row 1 should have a higher score given that the search terms words are closer together.
2. If I provide the search term: **Joh Smit** or **Smit Jon**, both rows should be returned but Row 1 should have a higher score given that the search terms words are closer together.

Currently, my SQL looks a bit like this:

```
SELECT display_value
     , score(1)
  FROM  my_indx_table
 WHERE contains ( search_tokens, '%' || replace(replace( :SEARCH_STRING, '_', '\_' ), '-', '\-') || '%', 1 ) > 0
ORDER BY score( 1 ) desc;
```

But it's not working as I intend.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the dark, terrible world of Oracle Text searching. (You might want to [read the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/GUID-7070C025-54E1-4FBB-8585-1FCBD525927D.htm#CCAPP9172).) Let's start with some setup, so I can replicate your issue.

```
create table my_indx_table (display_value number, search_tokens varchar2(100));
create index my_indx on my_indx_table (search_tokens) indextype is ctxsys.context;
insert into my_indx_table values (1, 'John Smith Bristol South West');
insert into my_indx_table values (2, 'John James Smith London South East');
commit;
exec ctx_ddl.sync_index(idx_name => 'MY_INDX');
```

Ok, here's your query. It only returns row 1, since that row has "John Smith" in exactly that sequence.

```
SELECT display_value, score(1)
  FROM  my_indx_table
 WHERE contains ( search_tokens, '%' || replace(replace( 'John Smith', '_', '\_' ), '-', '\-') || '%', 1 ) > 0
ORDER BY score( 1 ) desc;

DISPLAY_VALUE   SCORE(1)
------------- ----------
            1          3
```

If you want to do more than one kind of search at a time using a single CONTAINS call, you probably want to use [Query Templates](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/GUID-57BA56DA-CDEC-442A-BF2B-CB8BFEA7C001.htm#CCAPP9164).

This next example uses Query Rewriting and Query Relaxation. It first tries the exact phrase "John Smith", and then searches for the two words near each other.

```
SELECT display_value, score(1)
  FROM  my_indx_table
 WHERE contains ( search_tokens, 
'<query>
<textquery lang="ENGLISH" grammar="CONTEXT">' || 'John Smith' || '
 <progression>
   <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "{", "}", " "))</rewrite></seq>
   <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "{", "}", " NEAR "))</rewrite></seq>
 </progression>
</textquery>
<score datatype="FLOAT" algorithm="COUNT"/>
</query>', 
    1 ) > 0
ORDER BY score( 1 ) desc;

DISPLAY_VALUE   SCORE(1)
------------- ----------
            1       50.5
            2     6.8908
```

Row 1 gets a higher score than row 2, mostly because it contains the exact phrase.
If you remove the first `<seq></seq>` line (or try "Smith John") you'll notice that both rows get *very similar* NEAR scores, despite having different distances. The default score datatype is Integer, so both rows 1 and 2 would get rounded to the same score, 14. Probably not what you want. (I think the reason for this is that Oracle Text is mostly designed to index LARGE blocks of text, like documents or books. Its scoring is a little weird for short phrases like this.)

Now let's look at [fuzzy](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/cqoper.htm#GUID-5BA618D7-45DA-4253-BB0D-313970EA7C5D) searching, to account for misspellings. The default similarity score for this function is 60, but I lowered it to 50 so it would pick up Smit=Smith.

```
SELECT display_value, score(1)
  FROM  my_indx_table
 WHERE contains ( search_tokens, 
'<query>
<textquery lang="ENGLISH" grammar="CONTEXT">' || 'Joh Smit' || '
 <progression>
   <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "{", "}", " "))</rewrite></seq>
   <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "{", "}", " NEAR "))</rewrite></seq>
   <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "fuzzy(", ", 50)", " "))</rewrite></seq>
   <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "fuzzy(", ", 50)", " NEAR "))</rewrite></seq>
 </progression>
</textquery>
<score datatype="FLOAT" algorithm="COUNT"/>
</query>', 
    1 ) > 0
ORDER BY score( 1 ) desc;

DISPLAY_VALUE   SCORE(1)
------------- ----------
            1      25.25
            2     3.4454
```

Pretty straightforward, I think. The main confusing thing here is probably the query rewrite syntax. But there's a lot of tweaking you can do with the `fuzzy` operator, to get it to work with the specific searches you're dealing with.

Comment: Ha! Just today I attended the 2nd Apex Alpe Adria conference in Zagreb, Croatia (https://www.aaapeks.info/agenda/) . One of the speakers was Niall Mc Phillips, talking about Oracle Text. He mentioned pretty much everything you wrote here.

Comment: sweet. thanks so much for your detailed reply. I will work through it and get back to you. I often fell like oracle text is more art than science (and a black art at that)!

Comment: This is looking really good. Had to bumb the Fuzzy tollerance up to 55 but looking much better. Thanks for taking the time to help me understand.